# Getting currentScript is returning typeError

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a custom attribute that I put on my script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://.../mysource.js" customdata="some_value"></script>
```

I'm using the following code so it will work on IE:

```
document.currentScript =
  document.currentScript ||
  (function () {
    const field = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    return field[field.length - 1];
  })();

// document.currentScript.getAttribute('customdata');
```

But then I'm receving the following error when I try to set a new value on document.currentScript.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property currentScript of # < Document > which has only a getter

I only solve this when I'm using document.currentScript directly, but then I can't use on older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If `document.currentScript` exists, it's a read-only property. So only try to set it if it doesn't exist.

```
if (!document.currentScript) {
  document.currentScript = (function() {
    const field = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    return field[field.length - 1];
  })();
}
```

Comment: I'm using this code block inside the script. The script tag will always exists.

Comment: I assume this is a polyfill for old browsers that don't set `document.currentScript`.

Answer (score 0):

I created another variable to hold the value from document and then it worked and no errors is shown.